# How to remove the outer border of UITextField presented in UIAlertActionController

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uialertcontroller

I am adding multiple UITextFields to my alert controller, and I don't want that ugly black box around them.  I know it's not the border property of the textField, because I have tried setting that and that influences the actual textField, not the box.  [image]

I have tried

`textField.superview?.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
textField.superview?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor`

Setting the background Color works as expected, filling in the space between the textfield and the "black border" but setting the borderColor or borderWidth on superview.layer do nothing.  Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using UITextField? Does the text need to be editable?

Comment: No doesn't need to be edited, but the UIAlertController API supports embedding textfields, not textviews or other UIViews.  Id rather stick with that to be safe. I did try subclassing and using a textview, but it was pretty hackey trying to position it properly.

Comment: Why not use UILabel? Can you post the code where you populate the UIAlertView with text?

Comment: It's not an UIAlertView, but a UIAlertController

Comment: All right... edit your question and add the code there.

Comment: Code? I want to see how you are doing this. There could be several answers to your question.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up subclassing UIAlertController.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    for field in textFields! as [UITextField] {
        field.superview?.superview?.layer.borderWidth = 2
        field.superview?.superview?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    }
}
```