# Swift double unwrapping of Optionals

Tags: xcode, swift, option-type

I understand what optional are in Swift but I just encountered a *”Double Wrapped Optional’*, where if I don’t use two `'!'` Xcode gives an complier error

> Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or ‘?'?

I have the following code, where `app` is of type `NSRunningApplication`.

```
let name: String = app.localizedName!
```

Why should I have to use two `!`? Isn’t one enough to unwrap the variable because it is of type `var localizedName: String?`.

**Context:**
Xcode want me to use `let name: String = app.localizedName!!`, otherwise it gives the compiler error above. 
The `app` variable is defined as follow:

```
var apps = NSWorkspace().runningApplications.filter{$0.activationPolicy == NSApplicationActivationPolicy.Regular}
for app in apps{
    //code posted above
    …
}
```

So I know that `app` is not an optional and will always have a value, nor is it an optional application.

P.S. Is there a way to define type when using fast enumeration? Like `for Foo(app) in apps` where `apps = [AnyObject]`.

Comment: How exactly is `app` defined? Could it be an *optional* NSRunningApplication?

Comment: We're stumbling for answers because that line of code shouldn't produce that error. If app were optional, you'd get different error. And `localizedName` is not a "double optional" (lol). This line of code looks fine and should not generate that error. Swift, unfortunately, can generate misleading errors, and I wonder if the real problem rests in an earlier line of code (or perhaps you altered or otherwise cleaned up the line of code when preparing question). Also, when I get inexplicable errors, I clean the project, quit Xcode, empty the derived data folder, and restart Xcode.

Comment: @MartinR Added more info. Cheers for the help.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28247921/242933

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `NSWorkspace().runningApplications` returns an
array of `AnyObject` which has to be cast to an array of 
`NSRunningApplication`:

```
let apps = NSWorkspace().runningApplications as! [NSRunningApplication]
let filteredApps = apps.filter {
        $0.activationPolicy == NSApplicationActivationPolicy.Regular
}
for app in apps {
    let name: String = app.localizedName!
}
```

Comment: Xcode shows an error for the code above. You should probably replace `as` with `as!`: `let apps = NSWorkspace().runningApplications as! [NSRunningApplication]`

Comment: @Chris: You are right, that changed with Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.3), thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 2):

Here's why: `app` is of type `AnyObject` (`id` in Objective-C), and doing any lookup on `AnyObject` introduces a layer of optionality because of the possibility that the method doesn’t exist on the object. `localizedName` is itself Optional, so you end up with two levels of optional: the outer level is nil if the object doesn’t respond to `localizedName`, and the inner is nil if 'localizedName' is nil.