# Double optionals (??) and double unwrapping (!!) with Button text in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, option-type

I have a standard `UIButton` in a standard single view project. I want to get the text of the button when it is clicked. However, in Xcode 7.0 GM I am getting strange behavior with the compiler requiring me to use `??`, `?!`, or `!!`. When trying to unwrap the text there is more strange behavior: only triple unwrapping finally does it.

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    print( sender.titleLabel?!.text ) // Optional("Button")
    print( sender.titleLabel??.text ) // Optional("Button")
    print( sender.titleLabel!!.text ) // Optional("Button")

    print( sender.titleLabel?!.text! ) // Optional("Button")
    print( sender.titleLabel??.text! ) // Optional("Button")
    print( sender.titleLabel!!.text! ) // Button

}
```

What is going on here?

I have seen

- [Swift double unwrapping of Optionals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29351438/swift-double-unwrapping-of-optionals)
- [!? Strange double unwrapped optional syntax in for_in []?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28247612/strange-double-unwrapped-optional-syntax-in-for-in)

but the `sender` is not an array here, and I couldn't see the connection to those answers.

Comment: See [Interacting with Objective-C APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html): *"NOTE: Property access on AnyObject always returns an optional value."* and the following examples.

Comment: So the first Optional is for a property access on `AnyObject` and the second Optional is the normal `titleLable` Optional on `UIButton`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of `AnyObject`. The first `?` is for "is it an object that responds to the `titleLabel` method?", and the second `?` is for "is the title label nil?"

If you are only hooking up a **button** from Interface Builder, you can use

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton)
```

Comment: Ah, right. I'm still curious about the meaning of double optional or unwrapping, though. What is it about `AnyObject` that makes the compiler require that?

Comment: One `?` is for "is it an object that responds to the `titleLabel` method?" and one `?` is for "is the title label nil?"

Answer (score 1):

When you are sure that your sender is always `UIButton` then why are your input parameter as `AnyObject`. Below declaration would solve your problem:

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    print( sender.titleLabel!.text ) // Optional("Button")
    print( sender.titleLabel!.text ) // Optional("Button")
    print( sender.titleLabel!.text ) // Optional("Button")

    print( sender.titleLabel!.text! ) // Optional("Button")
    print( sender.titleLabel!.text! ) // Optional("Button")
    print( sender.titleLabel!.text! ) // Button
}
```

Comment: You're right. In this case the sender is always a `UIButton` so I should have marked it as such. I would still like to know, though, why the compiler is requiring the double optional/unwrapper for `AnyObject`.

Comment: Simply because your first level of object is not certain. It could be anything including nil so you better let compiler know what it is. You could do it by `if let button = sender as? UIButton { }` syntax as well and then fetch the `UIButton` properties inside. Its always a better practice to mention the right type and let compiler be certain pre-hand on the data type rather than we writing more code in making compiler understand that we know what could come in `AnyObject` at run time.